# What is the difference between nodal analysis and Superposition? Can I use nodal analysis in Superposition?

Tags: circuit-analysis

All I need to know is it possible to apply nodal analysis in superposition? For example lets see the following circuit:

I have to use superposition to find the voltage across the current source of **1A**.
What I've learned in circuit theory is we have solve it in this way:

```
 U(acreoss the 1A current)=U(3A)+U(14v)+U(1A)
```

Apparently to find U(14) is deactivating all the independent sources and work with only the 14v source, the same we do for U(3A) and U(1A).

```
1. for U(1a) I use the Current divider
2. for U(14v) I use Voltage divider
```

**PROBLEM:** `3. for U(3A) I use nodal Analysis`

My problem is not how to solve it, I just need to know which method should I use to find the (U(3A) without Nodal analysis, is there any other useful method.

After all superposition analysis leads to easy equations not like nodal analysis, but why in this case it leads me to nodal analysis?.

[image: Superposistion Circuit example]

Comment: For U(3A) you can also use current divider.

Comment: How? there's a GROUND between two resistors i think it's not possible but i would like to see how do you use the current divider in this case.

Comment: Because this is the only ground in the circuit, there is no current that can flow through it. Therefore when looking for U(3A), R2 and R3 are in series (this is the first branch) and then R1 would be the second branch. Once you have the current in the first branch U(3A)=current*R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Superposition is a meta solution technique for linear circuits.  When there are N sources, the circuit can be solved N times, by whatever analysis method you choose, with just one of each of the N sources activated.  The total of all the solutions is the actual solution.

> All I need to know is it possible to apply nodal analysis in
>   superposition?

Yes.  If, for example, you have 3 sources, you would solve for the node voltages 3 times, each time with only one of the sources activated, and add the 3 solutions together.